# How to extract coefficients' standard error from an "aov" model

Tags: r, anova

I did a `aov` model and I just want to extract the standard errors of each coefficient.

```
model <- aov(Molecule ~  Comorbidity + Age + BMI + Sex, data = mydata)
```

I can see the estimated marginal mean with:

```
allEffects(model)
```

But I can't extract standard error of each coefficient. I saw on the internet the function `se.coef()` but it doesn't work. `summary(model)$coefficients[, "Std. Error"]` does not work either.

I've read `effects` and other packages, but I don't find what I want. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `lm` method for `summary`:

```
coef(summary.lm(model))
```

This will give a coefficient table / matrix of 4 columns (mean, standard error, t-value, p-value) for all identifiable coefficients. Then you can extract the 2nd column for standard error.

`aov` returns object of primary class "aov" but secondary class "lm", hence both `summary.aov` and `summary.lm` apply but gives different things. When you simply do `summary(model)`, the former is called as the result of S3 method dispatching.

Comment: But then, I have a `lm`model, no an 'aov' model. I can plot my `aov` model with `plot.(allEffects(model))`, then I can see all Estimated marginal mean of all coefficients drawn, and also I can see Standard-error drawn. Those are the ones that I want.

Comment: @李哲源 Sorry, I have a doubt. The coefficients are the solution of fixed effects?