# extract values from time series forecast

Tags: r

I have an object `forecast`. When I execute:

```
class(forecast)
```

I get:

```
[1] "mts"    "ts"     "matrix"
```

Does this mean that this is a list of 3 objects of which the last one is a matrix?

When I do:

```
str(forecast)
```

I get:

```
 Time-Series [1:5, 1:3] from 8153 to 8157: 52 52 52 51 51 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "fit" "upr" "lwr"
```

When I do:

```
head(forecast)
```

I get:

```
          fit      upr      lwr
[1,] 51.77675 57.21211 46.34138
[2,] 51.67965 57.22266 46.13664
[3,] 51.58255 57.36042 45.80468
[4,] 51.48545 57.65884 45.31206
[5,] 51.38835 58.13347 44.6432
```

How do I get the separate values of the first row as indicated by this pseudo code please:

```
          fit      upr      lwr
[1,] 51.77675 57.21211 46.34138

fit <- ?
upr <- ?
lwr <- ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an object has multiple classes, it can be processed as any one class (although the generic function normally picks up the first class for method dispatching, see [How to extract coefficients' standard error from an "aov" model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41022222/4891738) for an example).

A "mts" class is for a multivariate time series, it is a mixture of "matrix" class and "ts" class. You can access it as an ordinary matrix.

```
forecast[1, , drop = FALSE]  ## row 1

fit <- forecast[1, 1]
upr <- forecast[1, 2]
lwr <- forecast[1, 3]
```